# Why Alt and Esc keys behave differently in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I am new to Emacs coming from Vim. I can use `Escape` as a Meta key (Alt key in my keyboard) with a small difference. I need to hold down the `Meta` key (Alt key in my keyboard) to use commands but in order to use same command by using `Escape`, I push it first, release ,and push the command.

I am thinking to map `CapsLock` to `Esc`. It shouldn't be hard to keep `Esc` key pressed down. What is Emacs' users configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Meta key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_key) was a feature on the keyboards (in particular, Lisp machine keyboards) at MIT where Emacs got its start. Many keyboards outside of MIT did not have a labeled Meta key. But many had an Esc key and that was chosen as a backup to the Meta key.

The Esc key already existed and was a good candidate. However,  keyboard technology would not permit its use as a modifier key (like Meta, Shift, Alt, etc.). Hence the strange difference which persists to this day.

Answer (score 2):

Emacs is different from Vim, because Emacs and Vim are fundamentally different programs.  They each have a long and rich history.

If you are wondering how to get started configuring Emacs, I recommend that you investigate the [Emacs Wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/).  If you would like a Vim-like experience in Emacs, you should try [EVIL](https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil), a Vi imitation layer for Emacs.  As an Emacs neophyte, [emacs.sexy](http://emacs.sexy/) has a list of resources for new users.

Comment: Yes but why Esc and Alt keys are behaving different as a `Meta` key. You need to keep `Alt` key pressed down but for `Esc` key, you need to press once to enter a command.

Comment: Meta and Control are "modifier" keys in Emacs.  They don't do anything on their own, they're only used in conjunction with other keys.  For example, `M-x` opens the minibuffer, and `C-x C-c` quits emacs.  Escape is a regular key, so while it can be used in conjunction with Meta or Control, it does not modify other keys.  So `M-Esc C-c` would be a valid keybinding, but `Esc-g C-z` would not be.  For more information, see the [Emacs Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Modifier-Keys.html).